# How come the contents of Text elements aren't being properly justified?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Consider the following page in a QML application:

```
Page {
    Text {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: units.gu(2)
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignJustify
        text: "aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa."
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    }
}
```

I expect that the contents of the `Text` element would be justified but this is clearly not the case:

[image]

As you can see, the first line is not justified as it should be. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your qml snippet in this qml file on Ubuntu 13.10:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1


MainView {
    id: main
    width: units.gu(30)
    height: units.gu(35)

    Page {
        Text {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: units.gu(2)
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignJustify
            text: "aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa."
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }
}
```

And I can say that it works perfectly, the text is properly justified:

[image]

Comment: Copying-and-pasting your code results in this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MICdj.png I didn't mention it in the question, but I'm using Trusty. This might be a bug.

Comment: Qt 5.2.1 landed in trusty last week. Which version is installed in your system? (type `qmake -v`)

Comment: I have 5.2.1 installed.

Comment: I can confirm the bug, just tested on trusty. All types of alignment work except justify.

Comment: Would you like me to file a bug on LP?

Comment: yes, please file a bug using the qt5.2 tag

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to tag the bug report. But anyway, here is a link to it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtdeclarative-opensource-src/+bug/1294940